# Facebook Api Graph can't get full info (JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

everyone. Trying to use Facebook api JS SDK. But all my trials end up with full name and id maximum. Like this way:

```
$("#getfacebook").click(function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Logged in.');
        }
        else {
            FB.login(function() {}, {scope: 'public_profile'});
        }
        FB.api(
            "/me",
            function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
                console.log("info", response)
            }
        }
    );
})})
```

But when I try something more like

```
FB.api(
    "/{page-id}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log("info", response)
      }
    }
);
```

or

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'cover'}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Everytime I got undefined. Mb proplem with scope??

Answer (score 0):

You need to request for proper permissions

Add them in the scope. Here is the list
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

And the documentation goes here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.6

Comment: So, as I can see no selector with selector '/me' response is always name and id. and I have to send request for every single field ... and also type every single perms I 'll use in scope ?

Comment: This permissions will be requested only once from the user when the user logs in for first time